# JQuery UI Autocomplete with Zend Framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, autocomplete

I was wondering about how to add the autocomplete JQuery UI widget to a form I'm developing in the Zend Framework without using ZendX. The folders for the website are set up per the framework, but I'm not using Zend_Form.

So I stripped everything down to the simplest form, which works:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["best", "buy"]
});
  });
  </script>

<input id="autocomplete" />
```

But I have a PHP file that returns entries from a database in JSON. How do I use that instead?
I tried replacing the array with the name of the file, but then nothing happens.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors in the browser?

Comment: I don't think so. The pages loads the same as before. :/

Comment: When you view the source of the rendered `Zend_From` page does it look like the path to the js file(s) is correct?

Comment: Please provide code sample if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work for you:

```
// js stuff
$( "input#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost/application/index/autocomplete"
});


//IndexController.php

/**
 * Return AutoComplete stuff
 */
public function autocompleteAction()
{
    // disable view and layout, we want some fanzy json returned
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); 
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $values = array('best', 'buy');
    $valuesJson = Zend_Json::encode($values);
    echo $valuesJson;
}
```

You could altough pass the BaseUrl to your Script (instead of using fullpath)

```
//layout.phtml
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseUrl = "<?= $this->baseUrl(); ?>";
</script>
```

So you could do:

```
source: baseUrl + "/index/autocomplete"
```

Comment: thank you! :) i think writing out the whole source path did the trick!