# How to implement jquery autocomplete using Zend framework 2?

Tags: jquery-ui, zend-framework2

I am looking for examples on how to implement jquery's autocomplete via zend framework 2.

Based on my previous experiences with autocomplete using java and coldfusion, the http response must be only the JSON data. but Zend would normally attach a layout HTML (as defined by the module config). I was thinking of using an empty layout file (contents would be content; ?>) but I'm not sure if this is the correct (i.e. Zend way) of doing this.

I've been searching the net but can't find anything useful.

Can you please help with examples/links/etc? thanks

Comment: This might help -> http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/

Comment: that's the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

To create the autocomplete, you need:

1. Create a controller to respond in json receiving the parameter by get or post.

.

```
public function searchAction(){
// GET
$Params = $this->params ();
$count = $Params->fromQuery ( 'count', 10 ); 
$offset = $Params->fromQuery ( 'offset', 0 );
$search = $Params->fromQuery ( 'search', null );

// Mapper
$Search = TableMapper ();
$rs = $Search->search ( search, $count, $offset )); 

//I think good idea create an restful service if you have anothers requests

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo \Zend\Json\Json::encode ( array (
        'status' => true,
        'data' => $rs,
) );
die (); }
```

2. jQuery / Angle collecting the letters typed in the field.

   ```
   $("#input").keyup(function(event) {
   var stt = $(this).val();
   /**
   The search is route example, you need put correct url/route
   **/
   $.get( "/search", function( response ) {
       if(response.status == true){
           $( ".result" ).html( response );
       }
   });
   });
   ```
3. html to show the response

   - [JQUERY copy contents of a textbox to a field while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160076/jquery-copy-contents-of-a-textbox-to-a-field-while-typing)
   - [JQuery UI Autocomplete with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002730/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-zend-framework)