# Is there / What is a suggested way to create autocompleted form fields in ZF2?

Tags: autocomplete, zend-framework2, textfield, zend-form, zend-form-element

Does the ZF2 Form ([`zendframework/zend-form`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form)) provide a mechanism to create text fields with autocompleted value list? Or is it just done by using the common `Zend\Form\Element\Text`, a `Controller`, that provides the data, and some JavaScript (not by ZF generated, but implemented in any proper way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Form doesn't have such mechanism, so proper way is use AJAX request with JSON response. See Rob Allen's tutorial for this:

[Returning JSON from a ZF2 controller action](https://akrabat.com/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery Autocomplete field with Any Framework or CMS, You can grab it here. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Its quite simple and easy to use.

You can fill source array on document.ready() or on field.change() or on field.keypress() events as per your requirements using Ajax.

Or you can read similar Resolved issue here 
[JQuery UI Autocomplete with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002730/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-zend-framework)